# Saving multiple subplots into one pdf using different functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have a user choose 4 directories using tkinter in "loadingfiles." From there, it loads all of the files from each directory.
how would I be able to save all of the subplots into a PDF. I know I have to do it from the main function, but how would I go about this?

```
def loadingfiles():
    #loads all of the files from each directory
    #returns Files

def initialize_and_Calculate(Files=[],*args):

    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_size_inches(9,5,forward=True)
    gs1=gridspec.GridSpec(1,2)
    ax0=fig.add_subplot(gs1[0,0])
    ax1=fig.add_subplot(gs1[0,1])


    #treat x and y as a parameter within a file in a directory. Can be any numbers


    ax0.plot(x,y,'-')
    ax1.plot(x1,y1,'-')

    fig.tight_layout()



def main():
    Files=loadingfiles() #this loads the files in directory
    L=len(Files)

    for c in range (0,L): #this for loops runs the initialize_and_Calc. function per directory.
        initialize_and_Calculate(Files[c]) #'File[0]' is directory 1. 'File[1]' is directory 2...and so on

    plt.show()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

If this doesn't make any sense, then how can I pass a 'fig' in a function. Say if I were to make a figure in my main function, how can I pass 'fig' to a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may return the figure from the function and append it to a list. Then you may loop through the list and save the figures to a pdf file.

```
from matplotlib import gridspec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import numpy as np

def loadingfiles():
    return range(4)

def initialize_and_Calculate(Files=[],*args):

    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_size_inches(9,5,forward=True)
    gs1=gridspec.GridSpec(1,2)
    ax0=fig.add_subplot(gs1[0,0])
    ax1=fig.add_subplot(gs1[0,1])

    x,y = zip(*np.cumsum(np.random.rand(20,2), axis=0))

    ax0.plot(x,y,'-')
    #ax1.plot(x1,y1,'-')

    fig.tight_layout()
    return fig



def main():
    Files=loadingfiles() 
    figures = []
    for c in range (0,len(Files)):
        figures.append(initialize_and_Calculate(Files[c]))

    with PdfPages('multipage_pdf.pdf') as pdf:
        for f in figures:
            pdf.savefig(f)

    plt.show()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Of course you may also create the figure inside a loop in the main function and pass it as argument to the plotting function.

```
from matplotlib import gridspec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import numpy as np

def loadingfiles():
    return range(4)

def initialize_and_Calculate(Files, fig ,*args):

    fig.set_size_inches(9,5,forward=True)
    gs1=gridspec.GridSpec(1,2)
    ax0=fig.add_subplot(gs1[0,0])
    ax1=fig.add_subplot(gs1[0,1])

    x,y = zip(*np.cumsum(np.random.rand(20,2), axis=0))

    ax0.plot(x,y,'-')
    #ax1.plot(x1,y1,'-')

    fig.tight_layout()


def main():
    Files=loadingfiles() 
    figures = []
    for c in range (0,len(Files)):
        fig = plt.figure()
        initialize_and_Calculate(Files[c], fig)
        figures.append(fig)

    with PdfPages('multipage_pdf.pdf') as pdf:
        for f in figures:
            pdf.savefig(f)

    plt.show()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```